# Docker container close after selenium download something

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-grid, docker-container

After selenium grid starts any download from any website the container closes. I tried selenium click and selenium execute_query but nothing works.

Comment: Do you have any logs? Have you tried to start an interactive shell and run the tests manually?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.